# App created with apache Cordova does't work on galaxy s3 mini (android 4.1.2)

Tags: android, apache, cordova, audiocontext, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I made this simple app with Apache Cordova. It must reproduce the sound of a sine wave at a certain frequency. The app is installed correctly on the device but does not play anything. It is as if he did not read the part of javascript. The code is correct. I do not know where the problem is.

I use these software versions:
Android 4.1.2
Cordova 8.0
API 27 26 16

This is the code:
[image: Link of the code]

Comment: Please put together a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and share the link to a repository (i.e. GitHub). This greatly improves the chances of someone take a look at your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Support of android version older than 4.4 has been removed in cordova android platform v7.1 so you should use older version if you want to use your app on smartphones runing android 4.1.2.

That said, on android before 4.4 the webview was not using chrome but the device's browser and I often had surprise with samsung's browser support of javasctipt/html 5.

Comment: I installed cordova 6.5.0 now but I still have the same problem

Comment: As I said maybe you are using javascript code not supported by the old samsung browser. Have you checked if you see errors in the js console?